# I am trying to figure out how to create a job that clicks a URL once a day

Tags: cron, cron-task

I have a URL, which calls some API and does some operations, I need this url to be clicked once a day. Can I use cron jobs, if so how? I tried the usual sites and methods, but they all make an API call. I need it to click my link.

Any help is appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Open `cron` via `crontab -e` and add a line like the below:

```
0 1 * * * node path/to/my_script_that_clicks_on_webpages.js
```

(make sure your script is executable)

More about scheduling with cron here:
https://crontab.guru/#0_1_*_*_*

Your next question might be *HOW* to "click a URL" (as you put it) via a node script (or any other script) but I think that's a separate question. (spoilers: you should use something like [playwright](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright) to click on a link)

---

For extra credit make sure you log the output of the script you're running via:

```
0 1 * * * node path/to/my_script_that_clicks_on_webpages.js >> /var/log/your_log.log 2>&1
```